# Why Ether-channel Index for Both Ports is same ?How Hash algorithm will work?

Tags: cisco, switch, etherchannel, port-channel

I have created a Ether-channel between Cisco 35060G and 2960G for practice purpose and to test Load balance .
Here is a output from

```
sh ether-channel detail
```

and it shows Index for both the ports as Zero.
My question is how Hash algorithm gonna work if both ports are assigned same index.

I choose Load Balance as src-dst-ip.
Please Guide me i'm new to Ether-Channels.
I'm using LACP.
[image]

Comment: I guess it's not the port index but the trunk group index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EtherChannel balances the traffic load across the links in a channel through the reduction of part of the binary pattern that the addresses in the frame form to a numerical value that selects one of the links in the channel. EtherChannel load balancing can use MAC addresses or IP addresses, source or destination addresses, or both source and destination addresses. The mode applies to all EtherChannels that are configured on the switch.

You can find out which interface is used in the EtherChannel to forward traffic based on the load balancing method. The command for this determination is

`test etherchannel load-balance interface port-channel`

Some extra options might need to be added to the command.

Source from Cisco ["Understanding Etherchannel load balancing"](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/etherchannel/12023-4.html)